# Complete projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve some exercise, which seems to be beyond me.

Let $P$ be a projection. "A projection $P$ is a linear map, that has the following property"<sup>1</sup>: $P*P=P$, where as $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Furthermore, $P$ is defined as
$$P = 
    \begin{Bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{2} & -1 & -1 \\
    \alpha & 0 & \beta \\
    \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
    \end{Bmatrix}
$$

Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so that $P$ is a projection.

---

#### What I tried:

I thought, by multiplying $P * P = P$, I should receive enough "equations", which allow me to find $\alpha \text{ and } \beta$.

So I tried and got the following result:

$$P * P =
\begin{Bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{2}^2-\alpha-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{3}{2}-\beta-\frac{1}{2} \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Which got me following equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{2} & = \frac{3}{2}^2-\alpha-\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \alpha = 0.5 \\
-1 & = \frac{3}{2} - \beta - \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \beta = 1\\
\end{align}
$$

However, inserting $\alpha = 0.5$ and $\beta = 1$ into $P$ and calculating $P * P$ yields $P * P \neq P$.

Where did I go wrong? Is this even a right way of solving this? If not, can somebody lead me to the right direction?

---

<sup>1</sup> Translated from the exercise I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed a negative sign on the last equation:

$-1 = -\frac{3}{2} - \beta - \frac{1}{2}$

$\beta = -1$

Comment: Thanks! Spent the last hour trying to find the mistake and overlooked it everytime.